# Independent paragraph indent

Tags: indentation

How can I indent a whole paragraph but omit the first word or words from indentation?

Example:

[image: Example]

Preferrable solution:

```
Abstract:
    \begin{adjustleftspacing}{2cm}
        \lipsum\[1-2]
    \end{adjustleftspacing}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
\documentclass[]{article}
\usepackage{lipsum,enumitem}
 \begin{document}
 \begin{description}[leftmargin=2cm,labelwidth=!,font=\normalfont]
 \item[Abstract:] \lipsum[1-2]
 \end{description}
 \end{document}
```

[image]